# migrate document library from parent site to subsite in sharepoint 2013

Tags: document-library, migration, sub-site

I have 10+ Document Libraries in the Parent Site. I want to move them to a subsite. What is the best approach without coding?

Comment: I would save them as template with content and create them from template in the subsite.

Answer (score 3):

Another option since the libraries are in the site collection is to use Content and Structure from Site Settings to move the content from parent to child site.

The nature of copying/moving the content will copy down any metadata associated with the parent list to the new destination, no need to worry about recreating the list/library structure, you just need an existing target.

Comment: Can we move list/libraries using this feature?

Comment: I dont think so we can do it with using Content and Structure...

Comment: Yes, it can be done with content and structure, revised.

Comment: can you do whole list or library not item by item?

Comment: batches of 1000 items at a time, used this method to shuffle 150k items around

Answer (score 1):

Couple of way to achieve it.

1. Use the Save the DL as "Save As template with include content option" then create the New DL on Subsite with those template one by one.
2. Using the PowerShell( export & Import), export the DL then import it on Subsite. Check this link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee428301.aspx
3. Use the 3rd party tools to Move the DL between the Site collections or within Site collection. check ShareGate as they offer free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Document Library --> Document Library Settings --> Save document library as Template

Give FileName, Template Name and check Include Content(if you also want to migrate documents inside document library).

Ok. And to upload Go in Site --> Site Settings ---> List Template --> Upload template here. Then it will be available under libraries.

Get in detailed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0f61826f-8488-4a3f-ac8e-64e1843f2e93/moving-a-document-library-from-one-site-to-another?forum=sharepointdevelopment), includes other solutions to get this migration job done.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can use below command to export the library

```
Export-SPWeb "http://sharepointurl/subsite1" -ItemUrl "LibraryURL" -Path "C:\" -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity"
```

Next import the library to new location

```
Import-SPWeb "http://sharepointurl/subsite1" -ItemUrl "lists/MyList" -Path "C:\"  -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity
```

Lastly remove library from the original location

```
$web = Get-SPWeb urlofweb
$library = $web.lists["listname"]
$library.Delete()
```

Comment: I would consider a PowerShell only answer coding, which was a requirement of his question.